# circulant Schur decomposition

Tags: unitary-matrices, schur-decomposition

Let $A_{1},A_{2},\dots,A_{m}$  be arbitrary $n\times n$ complex matrices.
Prove that there are $n\times n$ unitary matrices $Q_{1},Q_{2},\dots,Q_{m}$ such that matrices $$Q_{1}^{*}A_{1}Q_{2},\ Q_{2}^{*}A_{2}Q_{3},\ \dots,\ Q_{m-1}^{*}A_{m-1}Q_{m},\  Q_{m}^{*}A_{m}Q_{1}$$ are all upper triangular.

---

I have observed that we can use regular Schur decomposition to construct  $Q_{1},Q_{2},\dots Q_{m}$ that $$
Q_{1}^{*}A_{1}A_{2}\dots A_{m}Q_{1},Q_{2}^{*}A_{2}A_{3}\dots A_{m}A_{1}Q_{2},\dots
$$ to be upper triangular, but I don't know how to proceed then.